# Restaurar um dump PostGis 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando restaurar um dump de um base de dados postgresql com template postgis.

Quando tento restaurar o dump por terminal, tenho uma serie de erros.

Comando utilizado terminal:

> psql archeology -U cc1295225 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 45432 < saidas_owner.sql > error.log 2>&1

Os erros podem ser vistos do seguinte arquivo [error.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8602086/error.log)

E quando tento restaurar utilizando o pgadmin em Create script tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
COPY estado (gid, id, cd_geocodu, nm_estado, nm_regiao, the_geom) FROM stdin;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 13926: 1 6 35 SÃO PAULO SUDESTE 0106000060421200003B000000010300004...
            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 424037
```

### Duvida

Então como devo proceder para conseguir realizar o restore do banco com template postgis? Ou corrigir este problema de erro do dump.

Comment: Já tentou como superusuário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui com a ajuda de um amigo à descobrir uma solução. O postgreSQL não compreende as tabelas do postgis, para solucionar o problema é necessário transformar as tabelas em shapes e retornar a sql novamente uma por uma. Ainda não encontramos uma solução a qual o postgreSQL aceite todas de uma vez, porem esta solução de conversão já resolve parte dos problemas.

Então para resolver o problema utilizamos:

```
pgsql2shp
```

Para a conversão em shapes, e utilizamos:

```
shp2pgsql
```

Para converter novamente para o sql do postgreSQL.

Agradeço a tentativa de ajuda!.